# Make "How can I know what fonts a website is using?" a canonical

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

> Note, I'm making this post due to [this meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3216/23061). For discussion of whether or not to handle canonicals in this way, please discuss there.

I'd like to add the question [How can I know what fonts a website is using?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65366/23061) to our list of canonicals. It was originally written as a canonical so other questions could be closed as a dupe. I'd like to just add the [canonical](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) tag to it.

How about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's obviously made to be a canonical and should have the [canonical](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) tag.