# Canonical proposal - mockups

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-question, canonical-question

Per [this meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3216/41100) I'm proposing to make [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/113783/41100) a Canonical, so it can be used as a dupe hammer for similar questions like 'how do I mockup', 'free mockup tool', 'present photorealistic logo', etc.

Some similar questions, with varying degrees of quality in questions and answers:

- [How to achieve this 3D “Card” effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-achieve-this-3d-card-effect)
- [How can I create realistic business card mockups?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18514/how-can-i-create-realistic-business-card-mockups)
- [Creating 3D book cover mockups from scratch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113641/creating-3d-book-cover-mockups-from-scratch)
- [Turn die-line into 3D mock-up](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31929/turn-die-line-into-3d-mock-up) - kinda
- [How to do a prototype print of a business card](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15907/how-to-do-a-prototype-print-of-a-business-card)
- [A5 Double Gatefold mockup](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100014/a5-double-gatefold-mockup)
- [How to create 3D presentational mockup templates to showcase logo design to a client?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41025/41100)
- [How to use a vector mockup with perspective?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67874/how-to-use-a-vector-mockup-with-perspective) - though this is actually asking an Illustrator equivalent for smart objects
- [How to place text in perspective on product mockup](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84063/how-to-place-text-in-perspective-on-product-mockup)
- [Creating mockup template using inkscape for logo design presentation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41728/creating-mockup-template-using-inkscape-for-logo-design-presentation)
- [How to place UI gif in iPhone perspective mock for use on sites like Dribbble](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/how-to-place-ui-gif-in-iphone-perspective-mock-for-use-on-sites-like-dribbble)
- [How to create perspective like this in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48795/how-to-create-perspective-like-this-in-photoshop)
- [How do I create a mock-up photorealistic book and graphics and what free tool could be used?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28644/how-do-i-create-a-mock-up-photorealistic-book-and-graphics-and-what-free-tool-co)
- [How do designers render their work onto an iPhone/Android?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17143/how-do-designers-render-their-work-onto-an-iphone-android)
- [How do I create a mockup of an app on desktop and iphone?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39139/how-do-i-create-a-mockup-of-an-app-on-desktop-and-iphone)
- [How to create the 3D mock-up look](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58313/how-to-create-the-3d-mock-up-look)
- [“Skewed”/Inclined 3D Style Tile](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39049/skewed-inclined-3d-style-tile)
- [Problems with Photorealistic Product Mockups](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78559/problems-with-photorealistic-product-mockups)
- [What is the tool that web designers do to present prototype](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/what-is-the-tool-that-web-designers-do-to-present-prototype)

Comment: We should link all of these questions on the canonical one so that they can show up in the **Linked** on the side.

Comment: @WELZ Good idea. It's as easy as posting a comment with the link to the canonical Q/A

Comment: How do you link questions?

Comment: @WELZ consider it done

Comment: It can't be the target of a dupe hammer on GD if it's on GD meta instead of GD itself.

Comment: The main problem with canonical answers is that they fail to account for the nuance.

Comment: @joojaa I agree. In this case, a lot of the questions are exact copies though. At other times, it might be more interesting to link to the question and add more information or nuance in an answer. A Canonical is just a tool, it's available if needed, but shouldn't be used for things it was not intended for.

Comment: @PieBie well the how to make a polar array question is quite common

Comment: Did you ever make this canonical?

Comment: Ah, let me dig around in my ailing memory. I think the questions got linked, but the canonical itself was never created.