# Can we have a canonical "Adobe shortcuts" question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

I see frequently questions similar to "What's the shortcut for this in X" or [How to add shortcut key in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126019/how-to-add-shortcut-key-in-illustrator). A lot of times it's either Illustrator / Photoshop / Indesign, and it's always the same way (search it in "Edit > Keyboard shortcuts" and if yours doesn't exist, add it there).

I don't think the site should be a place to ask for the same basic software operation questions all the time, once should be enough! Don't get me wrong, I use shortcuts all the time and I love it, but whenever I need to find one I'd rather find a list of shortcuts than come here, ask for it, wait for an answer.

Should we have one general question + answer and just close the others / point to it? Something like

*Q: Where are the shortcuts for Photoshop/Illustrator/Indesign?*

*A: Search for it in [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html), [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html) or [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html). If you don't find a default shortcut for your tool, create one in the menu "Edit > Keyboard shortcuts".*

Perhaps with a link to the Adobe Default shortcuts (for example, [for Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html))

Comment: Aren't we then just recreating [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html), [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html) and [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html)?

Comment: @PieBie no, my idea is to have an answer that says "Edit > kbd shortcuts" and just the links to the Adobe pages, not replicating the pages on GD.SE. That way it stays up-to-date (as long as Adobe keeps their pages up-to-date)

Comment: relevant read: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/how-should-we-handle-canonical-qas. Be warned that a canonical Q&A needs managing, and some people will have to check its edits.

Comment: @Vincent sure, but in this case it should be a fairly low maintenance canonical (I believe) because these shortcuts don't change so often and we'd link to the actual shortcuts in the adobe website (which also doesn't change so often).

Comment: @Luciano .... You hope ;)